# Where can I find ActiveState Perl version 5.6.1?

Tags: perl

I wanted to test some Perl modules on `ActiveState Perl` `version 5.6.1` on Windows.
I googled, but doesn't get any site to download it. Is anyone knows about how to download it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Community Edition offers access to the newest versions of ActivePerl.
>   Access to older versions (Perl 5.6, 5.8, 5.10, 5.12) is available in Business Edition and Enterprise Edition.

So you'll need to buy access to the [business or enterprise editions](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl/downloads).

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. Is this is the final way to do such? I mean can't we get it from somewhere else?

Comment: The current community edition does not have a license that allows redistribution. Presumably older versions do not either, which makes ActiveState the only place you could get a copy from legally. (Happily, modern Perl development on Windows is well supported by Strawberry Perl, so ActiveState can be largely ditched. Testing for old versions of ActiveState is one of the few remaining use cases for sticking with them)

Comment: My company is using perl 5.6.1, I just wanted to test Perl script which uses XML::LibXML perl module for this specific perl version.

Comment: So either (a) Use the installer they have or (b) get them to upgrade, 5.6 is ancient and unsupported.

Comment: @ikegami — No, but it comes with enough dev tools that you can compiled most CPAN stuff out of the box.

Comment: To give a feeling of how old 5.6 is, 5.8, 5.10, 5.12 are also unsupported by the Perl devs. 5.14 and 5.16 are the two supported versions until 5.18 comes out in April (plus or minus).

Comment: I was suggesting upgrading to 16 :)

Comment: @ikegami — I've heard rather more positive things about the strawberry ones. Not much personal experience though, I have a copy of Windows mostly for games and running G+ on my gaming monitor.